# How can I understand why my code is not printed on the console?

Tags: python

There are a lot of solutions for the following problem

> Write a function that returns a new list of updated damages where the recorded data is converted to float values and the missing data is retained as "Damages not recorded".
>
> Test your function with the data stored in damages

```py
damages = ['Damages not recorded', '100M', 'Damages not recorded', '40M', '27.9M', '5M', 'Damages not recorded', '306M', '2M', '65.8M', '326M', '60.3M', '208M', '1.42B', '25.4M', 'Damages not recorded', '1.54B', '1.24B', '7.1B', '10B', '26.5B', '6.2B', '5.37B', '23.3B', '1.01B', '125B', '12B', '29.4B', '1.76B', '720M', '15.1B', '64.8B', '91.6B', '25.1B']
```

However I tried my own formula but it's not working. I cannot see the error behind my logic.

```py
damage_update = []
while len(damage) > len(damage_update):
  for damage in damages:
    if damages.find(M):
        damage_update.append(damages.update(1000000,0))
    elif :
            damages.find(B):
            damage_update.append(damages.update(1000000000,0))
        else:
            damage_update.append(damages.update("Damages not recorded"))
    print(damage_update)
print(damage_update)
```

Comment: You have syntax errors and you are using none existing functions.

Comment: There are indentation errors with your current code.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you'll need to do is wrap your code in a function and pass in your `damages` list as a parameter:

```py
damages = ['Damages not recorded', '100M', 'Damages not recorded', '40M', '27.9M', '5M', 'Damages not recorded', '306M', '2M', '65.8M', '326M', '60.3M', '208M', '1.42B', '25.4M', 'Damages not recorded', '1.54B', '1.24B', '7.1B', '10B', '26.5B', '6.2B', '5.37B', '23.3B', '1.01B', '125B', '12B', '29.4B', '1.76B', '720M', '15.1B', '64.8B', '91.6B', '25.1B']

def update_damages(damages):
    damage_update = []
    # your while loop here
    return damage_update

print(update_damages(damages))
```

Aside from that, your `elif` line requires a condition like your original `if` statement.

Also you are using `damages.update()` when lists like `damages` don't have a method called `.update()` and neither do strings. If you are trying to convert a string like `"40M"` into a float try something like:

```py
damage_update.append(float(damages[3].split("M")[0]) * 1000000)
```